# Difference between importing a module in app.module and a component

Tags: angular, import

**Angular 5**

What is the difference between importing a module in app.module and importing it in the component that it is to be used in?

More specifically, why should a module have to be a part of node modules, app.module, the `import` array in app.module and the component, before it can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Angular module is there to centralize your imports and dependencies.

Imagine you have 170 components, that all need `ToasterComponent`.

What seems to be the best suited : write 170 imports to the same component, or one line of import ?

So sure, you can use it directly in the component, but if the dependency is shared and used at other places, consider using a module.

Comment: Thanks! But if I do import a module in app.module, why do i need to further declare it in the imports array?

Comment: Because there's difference between importing it to load it, and add it as a dependency to your module. Consider this like variable scoping : unless you inject your dependency into your module, you won't have access to its variables.